# HIghcharts Aggregated Spline Marker Color

Tags: highcharts

I change the color and radius of my spline's marker as soon as it crosses a certain value by using point.update however now I am aggregating the data using dataGrouping and I have lost that ability. How can I color the aggregated data point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to update grouped points. Please check a thread in this github isssue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5147

However, you can use `attr` method directly on SVG point elements:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var points = this.series[0].groupedData;

            points.forEach(function(point) {
                if (point.y > 30) {
                    point.graphic.attr({
                        width: 8,
                        height: 8,
                        fill: 'red',
                        translateX: -2
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/58afeL47/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr